# Gmail: Remind me if my site is down

Tags: gmail, automation, http, nginx, maintenance

I desire to make my Gmail account to test if my website is down (if it doesn't return 200/OK [HSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) in a followed URL). I'll just pass a domain, choose timing (once per month / two months / other timing) and get a scheduled email:

> Your site doesn't return 200/OK, search for the problem.

Comment: Gmail is a email provider. I think you are looking for a way to receive an alert in gmail when site is down.

Comment: I know it is an email provider but it might have this functionality for customers who want it. I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Gmail nor any other Google service does this.

There are loads of external (and even free) services that can send you email or phone notifications. Pingdom, uptime robot, etc.